# exceptuar KeyError en programa de python 3.7.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, evaluación

estoy haciendo un programa que evalua expresiones matematica en mi python (anaconda 3.7.6)

pero me sale "KeyError" al poner algo que no sea una operacion matematica
intente varias veces pero no puedo encontrar donde es el error

```
import numexpr

def calc(ope):
    calcs = numexpr.evaluate(ope)
    if calcs == True:
        return "Verdadero"
    elif calcs == False:
        return "Falso"
    else:
        return calcs


print(calc(input("calculus>> ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que podes hacer es manejar el error con el keyword try: y except KeyError:

En el bloque de try se pone el error que posiblemente pueda suceder y en el bloque except se le especifica el tipo de error y se le dice en el caso de que el error suceda como lo queres manejar.

```
import numexpr


def calc(ope):
    calcs = numexpr.evaluate(ope)
    if calcs == True:
        return "Verdadero"
    elif calcs == False:
        return "Falso"
    else:
        return calcs

try:
    print(calc(input("calculus>> ")))
except KeyError:
    print('ingresa una operacion matematica')
```